# Javascript Object Property Initialisation

Tags: javascript

How can we initialize a `javascript` Object properties using a function?
The one I was trying but failed is mentioned below:

```
var myObject = {
        quatntity: 3,
        toalAmount: function () {
            return 599*this.quatntity;
        }
```

Please could you suggest the correct methods for doing the same.

Comment: I don't see any issue here; What isn't happening that you think should?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to create a getter to read in-literal sibling values.

you forget the `get` operator:

```
var ob={
        quatntity: 3,
        get toalAmount () {
            return 599*this.quatntity;
        }
};

alert(JSON.stringify(ob));
```

the nice part about them is that the value of `toalAmount` will self-update as the other values change, yet it's still serialize-able.

a lot of folks forget about getters, or think it's an ES6 thing (kinda looks like it), but they have been around since IE8/ES5...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

you also might want to simply make it a traditional method, the kind you need "()" to use, especially if you don't need JSON to include the value.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing bracket:

```
var myObject = {
        quatntity: 3,
        toalAmount: function () {
            return 599*this.quatntity;
        }
}
```

You can now retrieve that value by calling `myObject.toalAmount()`

Alternatively, you can set a `get` operator (as dandavis suggested) to retrieve the value as `myObject.toalAmount`

Side note - you should check your spelling:

- quatntity = quantity
- toalAmount = totalAmount

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the object the literal way. You can do it by using a function:

```
var myObject = function(){
    var quantity = 3; //private variable
    return {
      totalAmount: function(){
         return 599*quantity;
      }
    }
}()
```

Notice the () at the end of the function, so we are calling it and assigning the result to mybject. If you want to modify the quantity variable, you can create the function setter in the return value:

```
var myObject = function(){
    var quantity = 3; //private variable
    return {
      totalAmount: function(){
         return 599*quantity;
      },
      setQuantity: function(value){
         quantity = value;
      }
    }
}()
```

You can also create a constructor function and use `new` to instance new objects:

```
var MyObject = function(){
   this.quantity = 3; //public variable
   this.totalAmount = function(){
      return 599*this.quantity;
   }
}
var myObject = new MyObject();
myObject.totalAmount(); //1797
```

The constructor is commonly written with capital letter.

When you create an object using functions, variables with `this.` prefix will be public and `var` will be private